# Spring MVC REST JSON jQuery dynamic parameters for jpa query

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring, jpa

I need some technical input for this problem:

I want to search for a contract with different parameters. For now I search for five parameters: FromDate, EndDate, Season, Name and Category. In future it should be possible to search for dynamic way of parameters. All the parameters are values of contract domain object.

```
  var contract= {fromDate:moment($('#datepickerVon').val(), 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('DD-MM-YYYY'),
           endDate:moment($('#datepickerBis').val(), 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('DD-MM-YYYY'),
           season:$('#season').val(),
           name:$('#name').val(),
           category:$('#category').val()};

      $.ajax({
          url:'/contract/search/',
          dataType: "json",
          type: "GET",
          traditional : true,
          contentType: "application/json",
          data: contract,
          success: function(data) {

          }
          });
```

I used this controller method

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search/", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> getContractFromSearch(
        @RequestParam Map<String, String> allRequestParams, ModelMap model) {List<Vertrag> result = Contract.findAllContractsPerParameter(
            allRequestParams.get("fromDate"),
            allRequestParams.get("endDate"),
            Season.findSeason(allRequestParams.get("season").toUpperCase()),
            Name.findName(allRequestParams.get("name").toUpperCase()),
            Category.findCategory(allRequestParams.get("category").toUpperCase()));
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(Contract.toJsonArray(result), headers,
            HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Season, Name, Category are dependencies of Contract. So for the jpa query I need the full Object of each. For this I want a dynamical way instead of writing similar code for all. But I'm quite sure that there is another and better solution.
May be it is possible to do it with the contract object (domain and json) itstelf and also the jpa query.

Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Use command object binding in Spring MVC

Comment: Thanks for your input, can you give me some more informations. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with this example and it worked for me.

The json look now like this:

```
contract = {fromDate:moment($('#datepickerVon').val(), 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('DD-MM-YYYY'), endDate:moment($('#datepickerVon').val(), 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('DD-MM-YYYY'), Season: {
          season: "SO14"}, name: {name: "peter"}, category:{category:"SomeString"}};

          console.log(contract);
      $.ajax({
          url:'/contracts/search/',
          dataType: "json",
          type: "POST",
          mimeType: 'application/json',
          contentType: "application/json",
          data: JSON.stringify(contract),
          success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
          }
          });
```

The Controller receives like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search/", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> getVertagFromSearch(@RequestBody String json, UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder){
Contract contract = contract.fromJsonToContract(json);
    //do Stuff
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(Contract.toJsonArray(result), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And the deserialization is here:

```
public static contract fromJsonToContract(String json) {
    return new JSONDeserializer<Contract>().use(Calendar.class, new CalendarTransformer("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")).use(null, Contract.class).deserialize(json);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from your Description of problem I guess you can develop command object named Contract

```
 class Contract{

   private Date fromDate;   
   private Date endDate;    
   private String season;   
   private String name; 
   private String category;

// Getters and setters 

}
```

then you can pass it to your **getContractFromSearch(** method like below:

```
 public ResponseEntity<String> getContractFromSearch(
    @ModelAttribute Contract contract, ModelMap model) {
```

here Contract object will be populated by Spring Binder from your JSON data. You may need to write addition conversion logic of Date Objects.

Comment: yes sure, I have got the contract domain class and tried also your example. In my case contract gets no values from json, but I think it should have or not?

Comment: @Patrick - try to send only season , name , category first .  If it is successful we will go ahead for converting Date types.